# what is the default action for errors in fstab

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

In fstab, there is the option `errors=remount-ro` which I have seen here frequently.
Apparently there are 3 error options which seem clear to me:

- `errors=remount-ro` (attempts to mount the drive read only in error case)
- `errors=continue` (continues boot without mounting the faulty drive)
- `errors=panic` (boot into recovery mode if drive error)

Are my assumptions (in the brackets) correct?

What I want to know is what the default action is. My assumption would be that `errors=panic` is the default and the system goes in recovery mode if there are errors with a drive.

Comment: in the fstab you can specify as last option `pass`. `1` stands for main system disk, will get checked first by fsck on boot. All drives with `2` will get checked in sequence after and `0` wont get checked at all

Comment: maybe its better to remove this section for now if it's causing confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man mount`:

```
errors={panic|continue|remount-ro}
              Specify FAT behavior on critical errors: panic,  continue  without  doing
              anything, or remount the partition in read-only mode (default behavior).
```

so `remount-ro` is the default behavior, and the option could be omitted.

Comment: Thank you very much. `man fstab` did not specify this.
Do you know by any chance what causes the system to go into recovery mode if a disk is faulty then? Does this happen if `1` (system disk) is selected on the pass option?